# How to combine all xlsx files in a directory into a single xlsx file using R?

Tags: r

I have a directory with three xlsx files:

```
my_path <- c('Path/To/My/Stuff')
```

And each of the files has a name like this: `my-file_1.xlsx`, `my-file_2.xlsx`, `my-file_3.xlsx`

I want to combine these three files into a new xlsx workbook where each sheet contains all the data for one of these standalone files, and is also named after the standalone file (but only the `file_N` ending piece.

For example, the master workbook would be called `my-complete-workbook.xlsx` and it would have three tabs: `file_1`, `file_2`, `file_3`.

What's the best way to achieve this in R, ideally using the `openxlsx` library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this code -

```
library(openxlsx)

# Get list of files with .xlsx extension in current directory
filenames <- list.files(my_path, pattern = '\\.xlsx$', full.names = TRUE)

# Read all files
list_data <- lapply(filenames, read.xlsx)

# Assign correct names to list
names(list_data) <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(filenames))

# Write sheets
write.xlsx(list_data, 'file.xlsx')
```

Comment: This is not the answer I was expecting under this question. I don't want to read and combine the data. The task is simply to combine several .xlsx files into one .xlsx, keeping all the sheets --- I have searched around, but this (seems a very simple task) is not as straightforward as it looks.